# How do I programatically change a DockPanel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, dockpanel

**Note:** By Request, I have added the full code for my XAML and xaml.cs files.

In WPF, I have created a `DockPanel` like so:

```
<Window x:Class="RealEditor.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        Title="RealEditor" Height="500" Width="700">
    <DockPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <DockPanel x:Name="ftpDock" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></DockPanel>
    </Grid>???
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I want to programmatically add a `TreeView` to the `DockPanel`, but in Window1.xaml.cs, I am unable to get the `DockPanel` by name, and add to it:

```
namespace RealEditor
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
  public partial class Window1 : Window
  {
    public Window1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      TreeViewItem mytreeView = new TreeViewItem();
      ftpDock.Children.Add(myTreeView);
    }
  }
}
```

The above code returns the following error:

```
"The name 'ftpDock' does not exist in the current context"
```

I am sure I have just missed something simple. Any ideas?

Comment: Show more code, XAML and code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further testing and troubleshooting, I found that I was unable to reference any control added to Window1.xaml, not just the DockPanel. To fix the issue, I had to add "MSBuild:Compile" to the Custom Build field in the Window1.xaml File Properties.

I am unsure why that field was blank in my project, but hopefully this will help others experiencing the same "bug".

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your XAML is broken. You have an extra `</Grid>` which is un-associated with opening Grid tag.

I just created a project, copied your XAML and Code behind in, and apart from the captilisation difference and fixing the extra tag, mine works fine.

My Full XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <DockPanel x:Name="ftpDock" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TreeViewItem mytreeView = new TreeViewItem();
        ftpDock.Children.Add(mytreeView);
    }
}
```

Check all your tags and make sure you don't have any random extraneous tags floating around

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml, do you have the right class attribute for the window?

```
<Window x:Class="YourAssemblyName.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ftpDock" Grid.Column="1"></DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

See here: [WPF C# Classes, TextBox and Reference, Easy(?) "does not exist in the current context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503749/wpf-c-classes-textbox-and-reference-easy-does-not-exist-in-the-current-con)

Comment: Yes, the class attribute is correct in XAML, and I am attempting to access the DockPanel in the Window1 : Window class.

Comment: Where in the Window1 class? And what exactly does your xaml look like?  Cuz a .Window1 file like what I've posted above will allow you to access the ftpDock in the codebehind.  It is impossible to know how to fix your problem without more information.