# SIngleton Does Not Contain Error

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton

I am using WPF Browser Application and I have a page and a singleton.

In my singleton page, I have this code below:

```
           string check = textbox1.Text;

            if (duplicate.Contains(check) == true)
            {
                int remove = Math.Max(0, final.Count - 25);
                final.RemoveRange(0, remove);

                int delete = Math.Max(0, duplicate.Count - 5);
                duplicate.RemoveRange(5, delete);

                duplicate.Add(check);

                duplicate.AddRange(final);
            }
```

It pops out an error message that "the name textbox1 doesn't exist in the current context"

I am still new to WPF so help needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF C# Classes, TextBox and Reference, Easy(?) "does not exist in the current context"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503749/wpf-c-sharp-classes-textbox-and-reference-easy-does-not-exist-in-the-curre)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ColinE. But unfortunately, it's not working.